# Polymer computed function fails when the definition is in an imported file

Tags: polymer-1.0

I have a polymer custom element that uses some computed functions.
The functions work well when used in the defining file, however when used in a file that imports the defining file I get this error.
 compute method `typeIsSearch` not defined

Here is the example code

```
<template is="dom-if" if="{{typeIsSearch(type)}}">
    <label>text</label><input type="text" value="{{text::change}}">
</template>
```

and the function code

```
Polymer
...
    typeIsSearch: function(type) {
        return type === "search";
    },
...
```

Is it possible to call a computed function that is inside an imported file?

The custom Polymer element is in a file named geo-lookup.html.
Within that file the computed function works as expected.
However in another file index.html where it has the following import

```
<link rel="import" href="../geo-lookup.html">
```

The computed function call gives an error indicating it is not defined.  Non computed attributes including {{type}} are rendered properly in the including file.  I would expect the function to work the same in a file that imports the code as it does in the file it is declared in.  Any help on how to make it work would be appreciated.

Here is the full code of the index.html file

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>geo-lookup</title>

  <script src="../../bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>
  <link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/iron-ajax/iron-ajax.html">
  <link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/paper-styles/demo-pages.html">
  <link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/paper-slider/paper-slider.html">
  <link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/paper-radio-group/paper-radio-group.html">
  <link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/paper-radio-button/paper-radio-button.html">
  <link rel="import" href="../geo-location.html">
  <link rel="import" href="../geo-lookup.html">
  <style>
     .horizontal-section {
          max-width: 600px;
          margin-bottom: 24px;
      }

     label { display: inline-block; width:10%;}

  </style>

</head>
<body unresolved>
  <h1>GEO Lookup</h1>

  <div class="horizontal-section-container">
    <template is="dom-bind">

        <geo-location watch-pos latitude="{{latitude}}" longitude="{{longitude}}" accuracy="{{accuracy}}"></geo-location>
        <h2><pre>&lt;geo-location latitude="<span>{{latitude}}</span>"
            longitude="<span>{{longitude}}</span>"
            accuracy="<span>{{accuracy}}</span>">
            &lt;/geo-location></pre></h2>

            <div style="width: 100%">
                  <label>url</label><input type="text" value="{{url::change}}" disabled style="width:80%;"><br/>
                  <div>
                      <label>type</label><select id="typeSelect" value="{{type::change}}" style="width:10%;">
                           <option value="search">search</option>
                          <option value="reverse">reverse</option>
                      </select>
                      <paper-radio-group selected={{type}}>
                          <paper-radio-button name="search" value="search">search</paper-radio-button>
                          <paper-radio-button name="reverse" value="reverse">reverse</paper-radio-button>
                      </paper-radio-group>
                  </div>
                   <template is="dom-if" if="{{typeIsSearch(type)}}"
                      <label>text</label><input type="text" value="{{text::change}}" style="width:80%;"><br/>
                   </template>
                   <template is="dom-if" if={{typeIsReverse(type)}}>
                      <label>latitude</label><input type="text" value="{{latitude::change}}" style="width:80%;"><br/>
                      <label>longtitude</label><input type="text" value="{{longitude::change}}" style="width:80%;"><br/>
                  </template>
                      <label>size</label>
                      <div style="float:right;width:90%;">
                          <paper-slider min="1" max="40" step="1" value="{{size::change}}" editable style="height:20px;width:40%;"></paper-slider>
                     </div>
             </div>
            <div>
                  <geo-lookup url="{{url}}" type="{{type}}"
                            text="{{text}}" latitude="{{latitude}}"
                            longitude="{{longitude}}" size="{{size}}"></geo-lookup>
            </div>
        </template>
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You need to provide more context.

Comment: That's not much context. How should anybody see how things are connected from this information?

Comment: Importing `geo-lookup.html` doesn't do anything related to your problem. You need to add `<geo-lookup></geo-lookup>` somewhere and we would need to know where that is. Then you'd need to get a reference to this `<geo-lookup>` element, and then you could call `typeIsSearch(type)` on it.

Comment: I have updated the question with the full source code of the document. An example of how to get a reference to make this work would be appreciated.